# Longitude/Latitude from NetCDF with (row,column)

Tags: python, netcdf, sentinel-3

I downloaded a "Sentinel-3 Land Surface Temperature" netcdf file. I want to get the longitude and latitude for each temperature entry in the file. Well the file has pairs of rows and column. Using Python I can get the temperature using :

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

with dataset as ncFile:
    nc_attrValue = ncFile.variables['LST'][1000][1000]
    print(type(nc_attrValue))
```

So any idea how I can convert [1000][1000] to longitude or latitude. Here is a snapshot of the file netcdf file converted to .cdl using NCO:

```
    netcdf LST_in {
dimensions:
    columns = 1500 ;
    orphan_pixels = 187 ;
    rows = 1200 ;
variables:
short LST(rows, columns) ;
        LST:_FillValue = -32768s ;
        LST:add_offset = 290.f ;
        LST:long_name = "Gridded Land Surface Temperature" ;
        LST:scale_factor = 0.002f ;
        LST:standard_name = "surface_temperature" ;
        LST:units = "K" ;
        LST:valid_max = 32767s ;
        LST:valid_min = -32767s ;
// global attributes:
        :absolute_orbit_number = 12616U ;
        :comment = " " ;
        :contact = "eosupport@copernicus.esa.int" ;
        :creation_time = "20180720T144045Z" ;
        :history = "  2018-07-20T14:40:45Z: PUGCoreProcessor /data/ipf-s3/workdir47/568114279/JobOrder.568114279.xml" ;
        :institution = "SVL" ;
        :netCDF_version = "4.2 of Mar 13 2018 10:14:33 $" ;
        :product_name = "S3A_SL_2_LST____20180720T124923_20180720T125223_20180720T144045_0179_033_323_3240_SVL_O_NR_003.SEN3" ;
        :references = "S3IPF PDS 005 - i2r7 - Product Data Format Specification - SLSTR, S3IPF PDS 002 - i1r6 - Product Data Format Specification - Product Structures, S3IPF DPM 007 - i1r8 - Detailed Processing Model - SLSTR Level 2" ;
        :resolution = "[ 1000 1000 ]" ;
        :source = "IPF-SL-2 06.13" ;
        :start_offset = 21649 ;
        :start_time = "2018-07-20T12:49:23.587859Z" ;
        :stop_time = "2018-07-20T12:52:23.279310Z" ;
        :title = "SLSTR Level 2 Product, Land Surface Temperature measurement" ;
        :track_offset = 998 ;
data:

 LST =
  _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, 
    _, _, _, _, _, _, _, -7188, -6706, -6884, -6249, -6173, -6721, -6924,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Imports
from netCDF4 import Dataset

# Define reading function
def slstr_read_nc(fdir):
    """
    Read lon, lat SLSTR data
    
    Args:
        fdir = string with the path and filename of the SLSTR product
    Returns:
        lon -- 2d ndarray of longitude
        lat -- 2d ndarray of latitude
    """
    # Read Data
    # Open NetCDF
    nc = Dataset(fdir, mode='r')
    
    # Read variables from ncdf
    lon = nc.variables['longitude_in'][:]
    lat = nc.variables['latitude_in'][:]

    # Close netcdf
    nc.close()
    
    return lon, lat

# Define path and NC filename
path = './'
fname = 'geodetic_in.nc' # this is the lat, lon NC file
fdir = os.path.join(path, fname)
# extract lat, lon
lon, lat = slstr_read_nc(fdir)

lon.shape
lat.shape
```

Output:

```
>>> lon.shape
(1200, 1500)
>>> lat.shape
(1200, 1500)
```